# Connect visual studio 2019 to xampp

Tags: .net-core

I am a student and an apprentice developer. Currently I have been assigned a .NET core mvc project, the task I have to perform is to deploy the project on my own computer and test the CRUD.
I have a windows 10 on my machine. I have already installed visual studio code. For the database I use xampp - mysql.
I would like you to help me to connect visual studio with xampp to test the CRUD. Thank you very much. If you have a link or tutorials you can send them to me too. Thank you!!!

Answer (score 0):

You can build data-driven apps using Object Relational Mapper (ORM) like **Entity Framework Core** or **Dapper**.
Both Dapper and EFCore work with many SQL databases like SQL Server, MySql, PostgreSQL, SQLite, and so on. You can pick the database of your choice.

For more information and tutorials you can visit the official documentation for EfCore on the Microsoft Docs website:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/

In order to deploy your .NET Core app, you can build your project in release mode and deploy it on IIS which comes pre-installed on a Windows machine. Refer to the following link to know more about hosting .NET apps on IIS:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/iis/?view=aspnetcore-5.0